# Whats the reason UIButton's titleLabel is optional?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Whats the reason UIButton's titleLabel is optional?

Is it safe to implicitly unwrapped this optional by placing an exclamation mark? If not, what is the case when titleLabel is nil?

BTW, I use `UIButton.titleLabel` to change UILabel properties which are not directly accessible from UIButton, for example to change font or to have multiline label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is not to force unwrap, but you can pretty much guarantee a `UIButton.titleLabel` exists when you need it. I'm not 100% sure of the syntax but it's some form of lazy loading that isn't `lazy var titleLabel:UILabel = {}()`

Personally I'd say if you're concerned about unwrapping I'd use `guard` or `if let`

```
guard let label = myButton.titleLabel else {return}
label.font = .systemFontOfSize(10.0)
```

`if let label = myButton.titleLabel { label.font = .systemFontOfSize(10.0) }`

Answer (score 1):

Because a Button can be without any `Title` assigned to it. Sometimes only Image is required.

Hence in certain case when you'll try to access the Button's Title, without assigning one, the app might crash.

Comment: Not true. `let btn = UIButton()` followed by `print(btn.titleLabel == nil)` always prints false as far as I know.